# How can I get a screenshot in c

Tags: c, linux, screenshot

How can I get a screenshot in c .I want to do this without any other lib,just stand c.will you provide the whole code source for me? thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Stackoverflow is not a code provider

Comment: Only C, without a ilbrary? Then you should start digging deep in the memory mappings of your OS i guess. Just use a library that will do the job, otherwise it comes down to writing a 'library' yourself.

Comment: Hm,I want to take it to any OS,like java app(JVM)

Answer (score 3):

Standard C has no library functions that can be used for this. Standard C doesn't even know about screens. You need to use system-specific calls. If you are using Linux, you are probably using the X window system, so look at that. Its library is called [Xlib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xlib). Or, much simpler, find a program that takes a screenshot, and just use the function [system()](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.13.html#system) to call that program.